# Group only some headings

Tags: tables, formatting

I want to do something like this:

[image]

It has two headings: the upper one I'm done with but now I want to add a lower heading for only some columns. Is there a way to add such a heading in latex?

My attempt:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}\hline \hline
 & Whole world & Base sample & Whole world & Base sample & Whole world & Base sample & Whole world & Base sample \\
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) \\ \hline \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent variable is log GDP per capita in 1995 } \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
```

Comment: What should we do if we want to skip the first column? So the heading "Dependent var..." starts from second column?

Answer (score 1):

With `booktabs` and `makecell`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
 \thead{Whole\\ world\\ (1)}
   & \thead{Base\\ sample\\ (2)} 
     & \thead{Whole\\ world\\ (3)}
       & \thead{Base\\ sample\\ (4)} 
         & \thead{Whole\\ world\\ (5)}
           & \thead{Base\\ sample\\ (6)} 
             & \thead{Whole\\ world\\ (7)}
               & \thead{Base\\ sample\\ (8)} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead[b]{Dependent variable is log GDP \\per capita in 1995} } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Dependent\\ variable is log\\ output per\\ worker in 1988 }}  \\
\cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.54  \\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What should we do if we want to skip the first column? So the heading "Dependent var..." starts from second column?

Comment: Probably `& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead[b]{Dependent variable ...}` in combination with `\cmidrule{2-6}` is closer to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second line as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm,}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
Whole world & Base sample & Whole world & Base sample & Whole world & Base sample \\
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Dependent variable is log GDP per capita in 1995}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dependent variable is log GDP per capita in 1998}\\\cline{5-6}
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Then you will get the result:
[image: example table]

Comment: What should we do if we want to skip the first column? So the heading "Dependent var..." starts from second column?

Comment: To skip the first column you should delete the first item of each line.